# spring asm with custom classloader

Tags: java, spring, classloader, aop, encryption

Our app is over SSH,we add a custom classloader to keep class safe, but after encrypted the class file , the app can't startup. It seems spring use asm to load the class file ,and as of the file was encryted , it can't load it successfully. Is there any way to make it? Or how can i use spring without asm?

Comment: Spring asm do not load class but read it. does your app have any scan settings like <context:scan>

Comment: Thank you ,I've resolved it.Spring asm read the class file, and if you want to encrypt you class,you need to decrypt in asm class